# How should I think when querying for Parse.com relational data?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Parse.com does not allow querying for more than one object per query. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to work with this limitation.

My basic web app allows users users to log in, create foos, and then search through foos from other users near them. Users can leave references for other users, and can flag foos that are inappropriate.

To display the foos near them, I'm already doing 4 queries:

1. Get near users
2. Get reference counts belonging to the results of 1
3. Get foos belonging to the results of 1
4. Get flags (to indicate already-flagged) belonging to the results of 3

and this app is still young–I expect it to get more complex. This raises a bunch of questions:

- I traditionally try to limit how many network requests I make for performance reasons. Is it possible to package my query results into one?
- Parse's pricing depends on requests–how can I reduce how many requests I make? Does each query in `cloudcode` still count as a request?
- Should I be caching query results client-side?
- How do I manage pagination with so many requests/queries?
- When querying for relational data, should I repeat the first query (`.include()`) or should I pass in the list of objects (`.containedIn()`)?

Answer (score 0):

> I traditionally try to limit how many network requests I make for performance reasons. Is it possible to package my query results into one?

Yes, you can send a batch request, but cloud code is a better option

> Parse's pricing depends on requests–how can I reduce how many requests I make? Does each query in cloudcode still count as a request?

Yes (as do each of the requests in a batch)

> Should I be caching query results client-side?

Generally it's a good idea, if only to support pagination and some level of offline support (if you need that)

> How do I manage pagination with so many requests/queries?

Depends how you sort. If you sort by all of the food for closest users it's pretty easy to remember the query offset. If you're sorting by closest food it's really hard without specific data model setup so you know the location of each foo in the data store

> When querying for relational data, should I repeat the first query (.include()) or should I pass in the list of objects (.containedIn())?

You're generally better off using include if you can to get more data back in your results. Contained in is used for filtering rather than getting more data back though...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you edit with more details? 1. Are "batch requests" available in the javascript SDK? 2. Pagination is still confusing. Location is a field of user. Users can have unlimited foos. Because the queries are separate, I must paginate both users and foos. How do I keep them in sync?

Comment: IIRC batch is only via the REST interface. For unlimited you should use a relationship and then you have a relationship to query where you can set limit and skip. There is no single solution to pagination, you need to setup a custom system to track it - your situation is more complex than most others.